Deploying OpenStack using Ansible to LXC while cloud-app is used to grab for Kolla-Ansible
How do you estimate the probability of any built-in Docker runtime dependency in cloud app in situation when the (OpenStack-)cloud-based project appears to be used to apply Kolla Ansible to deploy OpenStack-based cloud?
In mission imminent here a cloud-based project is going to be in use - it will play a major role in my project. 3rd-party project is based on OpenStack cloud and recommends in documentation to use Kolla Ansible in order to set up (underpinning) OpenStack-based cloud - former uses one apparently Docker. Docker use is the component which triggers me to ask this question.
My own preference would be rather to deploy OpenStack to LXC-containers. One can find in OpenStack web the project Ansible-based deployment to LXC containers.
I wonder following if cloud-project developers could had placed in their project any runtime built-in Docker dependency by the use of Ansible Kolla for OpenStack deployment. Considering my very flat knowledge of Docker (only familiarized with its purpose and very few exercises made in far past) there exists just hypothetical risk for cloud project in my focus to feature built-in docker dependency. Should such dependency be a fact instead of risk, my aim to use OpenStack services in LXC-containers instead will fail.
It is hard to contact 3rd-party cloud project developer regarding my questions.
Question 2
Any common conclusions had been drawn so far if one of the two approaches be of remarkably higher suitableness to host OpenStack-based cloud services?

placing OpenStack-based cloud services to Docker-based containers
placing services of OpenStack-based cloud to Linux containers (LXC/LXD/...)

